# Manipulating data in a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, waterfall

I have a nested function that does some I/O and calls a callback once it has finished with the resulting data. Something like this:

```
function getStatus(returnCallback, errorCallback) {
   sendRequest('someData', returnCallback, errorCallback)
}
```

whereby sendRequest() is a function that interacts with hardware and calls the returCallback with the data that it got from the hardware or the errorCallback in case something went wrong. 
My problem now is, that the data that the hardware returns is a really long string that consists of different numbers that represent different parameters. What I want to do is manipulate the data that is given to the returnCallback and create and object with a property for each parameter. Is there a way to do that? I already tried using async.waterfall

```
function getStatus(returnCallback, errorCallback) {
        let returnArray = {};
        async.waterfall([
            function (callback) {
                sendRequest('someData', callback, errorCallback);
            },
            function (data, callback) {
                returnArray.statusBits = data.slice(0, 6);
                returnArray.faultBits = data.slice(7, 13);
                returnArray.alertBits = data.slice(14, 20);
                returnArray.pumpRotationSpeed = parseInt(data.slice(21, 26));
                returnArray.motorPower = parseInt(data.slice(27, 31));
                returnArray.frequencyConverterTemperature = parseInt(data.slice(36, 39));
                returnArray.pumpOperationTime = parseInt(data.slice(44, 48));
                callback(null, returnArray)
            }
        ], returnCallback(returnArray));
```

but that does nothing. As it looks the second function in the waterfall is never called. This might be because the callback from the first function is not structured as expected in the waterfall and it returns with *callback(data)* instead of  *callback(null, data)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `async.waterfall` callback, the first argument is `error`, also, you are supposed to wait for the end of the waterfall before exiting the function. The correct code would be:

```
function getStatus(returnCallback, errorCallback) {
    let returnArray = {};
    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            //First step
            sendRequest('someData', function (data) {
                //Everything is fine, continue
                callback(null, data);
            }, function (error) {
               //Error, skip all remaining step, and handle the error
                callback(error);
            });
        },
        function (data, callback) {
            //Second step
            returnArray.statusBits = data.slice(0, 6);
            returnArray.faultBits = data.slice(7, 13);
            returnArray.alertBits = data.slice(14, 20);
            returnArray.pumpRotationSpeed = parseInt(data.slice(21, 26));
            returnArray.motorPower = parseInt(data.slice(27, 31));
            returnArray.frequencyConverterTemperature = parseInt(data.slice(36, 39));
            returnArray.pumpOperationTime = parseInt(data.slice(44, 48));
            callback(null, returnArray)
        }
    //In normal case, error will be null, and the param will be the last passed to the callback of the last step
    ], function (error, returnArray) {
        //If there is a error (like error in step 1)
        if(error) {
            //Handle the error
            errorCallback(error);
        } else {
            //No error, continue with the normal callback
            returnCallback(returnArray);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there actually a way to incorporate the fact that I have a second callback function which is responsible for the errors? So that the waterfall is stopped when sendRequest returns an error? Something like 
`sendRequest('someData', functon (data) {callback(null, data)}, function (error) {callback(error, null)})`

Comment: You don't do it like that with waterfall, the goal is to go at the end of the waterfall, either by skipping all remaining step if error, or passing along, and at the end of the waterfall, check for error and handle them.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. My function has two callbacks and I can't change that without a huge amount of work. How can I let the async.waterfall know that an error occurred in the sendRequest function (the errorCallback was called and not the returnCallback) so that it skips to the end?

Comment: By not calling the `errorCallback` directly, and instead passing a anonymous callback which will pass along the error, since a error will be passed, `waterfall` will skip to the end, so you can call your error callback. Look at my edit, it should be what you are need :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

> manipulate the data that is given to the returnCallback and create and
>   object with a property for each parameter.

You have

```
function getStatus(returnCallback, errorCallback) {
   sendRequest('someData', returnCallback, errorCallback)
}
```

If  I understood what you are trying to do,

```
function getStatus(function(err, status) {
   if (err) return new Error('Something went wrong');
   else  sendRequest(status);
}
//get what you need here
var status = ... )
```

Here, the `getStatus` function start by executing the callback function in a parallel  process. The `status` and `err` parameters will be place as placeholders in the memory. At the same time, the `getStatus` is doing what he needs to do to retrieve the status that you want and store it as a variable. When the reading is done, the result is place inside the placeholders of the parallel process and then  the execution is finished.

This asynchronous method is coming from the fact that you are reading data inside hardware and it takes some time to retrieve it. The synchronous way would have block the tasks and wait for every steps to be completed, while asynchronously, it allows to not block at every step, but start the other tasks while it is finishing the previous ones.